# BIC is over-fitting the number of components in an image segmentation model using GaussianMixture from scikit-learn

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am using a GMM to segment/cluster hyper-spectral image data which is 800x800 pixels and 4 bands.

I took a picture and applied a GMM to cluster pixels.
Now, in my current situation, it is easy enough for me to manually determine how many components are in an image. (Grass,water,rocks... etc)
I have manually run the GMM on my data from n_components=3..8 and have determined that 5 components is probably the best n_components to model reality.

In future applications, I will need the ability to automatically identify n_components I should be using in my GMM, because manual determination will not be possible.

So, I decided to use the BIC as a cost function to determine the proper n_components to use in the model. 
I ran the BIC on the test data where I manually determined that n_components=5 best models reality and found that the BIC horribly over-fits my data. 
It is suggesting that I use as many components as I possibly can.

```
newdata=img_data.reshape(800*800,4)
n_components = np.arange(1, 15)
BIC = np.zeros(n_components.shape)

for i, n in enumerate(n_components):
    gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n,
          covariance_type='tied')
    gmm.fit(newdata)

BIC[i] = gmm.bic(newdata)
plt.plot(BIC)
```

[image: BIC Scores as a function of N_components]

Now ideally, I would like to see my BIC score minimized at 5, but as you can see above it looks like it is continually decreasing with n_components.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? Maybe I need to smooth the data in someway to reduce noise before using the BIC? Or am I improperly using the BIC function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little bit of googling, I decided to apply a simple Gaussian smoothing filter to my array and it seemed to produce a local min in my BIC score list which was the n_components which I expected. I wrote a small script to pick out the first local min and use it as a parameter for my gmm model.

```
newdata=img_data.reshape(800*800,4)
#Apply a Gaussian smoothing filter over a pixel neighborhood
newdata=sy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(newdata,(1.5,1.5))
#Create the vector of n_components you wish to test using the BIC alogrithm
n_components = np.arange(1, 10)
#Create an empty vector in which to store BIC scores
BIC = np.zeros(n_components.shape)

for i, n in enumerate(n_components):
    #Fit gmm to data for each value in n_components vector
    gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n,
          covariance_type='tied')
    gmm.fit(newdata)
    #Store BIC scores in a list
    BIC[i] = gmm.bic(newdata)

#Plot resulting BIC list (Scores(n_components))
plt.plot(BIC)
plt.show()
```

[BIC Scores With Smoothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEZIl.png)